# Styling the HTML5 Range Bar - Left of Thumb | Right of Thumb

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm using a range slider for a video seek bar in my html5 video player and I would like to know if there is a way, without using ***jQuery or jQuery UI*** to style the input range bar so that the background to the LEFT of the thumb is one color, but the RIGHT is another color.

Imagine what you see on the YouTube video player, the unplayed portion of the video seek bar is that dark gray, but the portion that has been played is red.  I want to recreate that, even if I have to use two empty divs and then control the width percentage with the slider through javascript...

But I'm hoping for a more stable built-in solution.

## ***UPDATE***

I have created a simple function that SHOULD update a css3 gradient in the background, but it doesn't seem to be updating.  The alert I have in the function works exactly how it should, but for some reason the value I pass through the function is not setting the gradient stops along the way.

HTML:

```
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="updateStyle(value)">
```

JS:

```
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");

function updateStyle(v){
    c = 100 - v;
    seekslider.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%, #ed1e24 "+ v +"%, #191919 "+ c +"%, #191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ed1e24), color-stop("+ v +"%,#ed1e24), color-stop("+ c +"%,#191919), color-stop(100%,#191919))";
    seekslider.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ c +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ c +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ c +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ c +"%,#191919 100%)";
    alert(v +" + "+c+" = "+(Number(v)+Number(c)));
}
```

## ***UPDATE***

The script does work - but not if the value of the slider is under 50

Comment: I would ask if you could please keep all comments to the subject matter of the question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is only working when `v` exceeds 50 is because you are using `v` as a left-bound limit for the gradient and `c` as a right-bound limit — when `v` falls below 50, the value of `c` will be more than 50 causing the limits to overlap. In other words, this causes the colour stops to overlap, with the second colour stop being further away than the third colour stop. The browser will therefore ignore the invalid colour stops.

In fact, you only need to access `v` and need not perform any calculations for `c`. See fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qsLeo3bc/ I also recommend using event listeners instead of inline JS. For the HTML, simply remove the inline JS binding:

```
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
```

...and for the JS:

```
var seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");

seekslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var v = this.value;

    seekslider.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%, #ed1e24 "+ v +"%, #191919 "+ v +"%, #191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ed1e24), color-stop("+ v +"%,#ed1e24), color-stop("+ v +"%,#191919), color-stop(100%,#191919))";
    seekslider.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ v +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ v +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "-ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ v +"%,#191919 100%)";
    seekslider.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,  #ed1e24 0%,#ed1e24 "+ v +"%,#191919 "+ v +"%,#191919 100%)";
});
```

Comment: this works when you are simply clicking through the seekbar, but does not update while the video is playing.

Comment: You didn't include that detail in your question. You asked about the styling, and not about coupling the video progress with the input slider — giving the impression you've gotten that part figured out.

Comment: my first sentence: **I'm using a range slider for a video seek bar in my html5 video player...** I assumed that it was implied that because it was for a video player, that the progress would be constantly updated.

Comment: Check this out: and just swap the `<progress>` element for your `<input>` element. http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/

Comment: What are you thoughts of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874143/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-slider-to-update-in-real-time

Comment: ***EUREKA!!!***  By attaching this function to the video itself and setting the AddEventListener to listen to the video's **timeupdate**, the seek bar now tracks along the input in real time. Thank you for the direction @Terry

Answer (score 5):

I did a cross-browser solution (+ie9, ff, chrome, safari), only with pure css.

http://codepen.io/nl_fonseca/pen/MwbovQ

```
input[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 45px;

    &:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none;
    }

    &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: #666;
        height: 3px;
    }

    &::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 50%;
        left: -200px;
        background: #e00;
        content: '';
        height: 3px;
    }


    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    &::-moz-range-track {
        width: 45px;
    }

    &::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;

        -moz-appearance: none;
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    &::-moz-range-progress {
        background: #e00;
    }

    &::-ms-track {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-width: 0;
        color: transparent;
        height: 3px;
        width: 45px;
    }

    &::-ms-fill-lower {
        background: #e00;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    &::-ms-fill-upper {
        background: #666;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    &::-ms-thumb {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }

    &::-ms-tooltip {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when slider width needs to be a percentage, rather than an integer.

Comment: It works but you need to do a little workaround. You have to put a really high number on the "for" of the function makelongshadow().

Comment: Could you show us the alternative for the % bit, please? @mwieczorek yeah I did try it myself as well

Comment: I really like this solution but I need the thumb to expand while hovering over it. I achieved this but now the expanded thumb is cut off by the borders of the element.

Adding a margin-left helps but a margin-right leaves a bit of the track visible. How can this be achieved?

Code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NavBYR

Comment: @Scyla101 you are scaling the thumb and also the right line (gray line), so what you can achieve is not possible, at least this way.